# map routing not using default action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, maproute

when I enter - http://localhost:60559/movies
The browser is redirecting to movies/index
Why? I have made the default action edit. All the names are just demo.

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "searchByName",
  "Movies/edit",
  new {Controller = "Movies", action = "edit"}
);
```

actions are

```
public ActionResult index(int? id) {
   if(!id.HasValue)
      id = 2;
   return Content("id: " + id);
}
public ActionResult edit(int? id) {
   if (!id.HasValue)
     id = 1;
   return Content(String.Format("id =  {0}", id));
}
```

the expected result is id = 1 in the browser but it is showing id: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ive tried your code and it didnt work well but
Please try the following and you code should work just fine

```
        routes.MapRoute(
           name:"searchByName",
           url: "{controller}/{action}",
           defaults: new { Controller = "Movies", action = "edit" }
      );
```

if you plane to add parameters then use following

```
        routes.MapRoute(
           name:"searchByName",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { Controller = "Movies", action = "edit", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
```

Please Add the following

```
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
               name: "SearchByName",
               url: "Movies/{action}",
           defaults: new { Controller = "Movies", action = "edit" }
           );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

Comment: routes.MapRoute(
           name:"searchByName",
           url: "{controller}/{action}",
           defaults: new { Controller = "Movies", action = "edit" }
      ); it is overloading the default router and I do not want that. I just want the when I enter only Movies controller automatically the edit action is selected.

Comment: Thanks for you reply @RitwikMath I've updated the answer to your issue please add the custom route first or it wont map correctly

 for More information please check out the following link 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2